# SSRS date conversion works on preview but not on deployment server

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services

OK, am a bit confused, I have an expression that turns the date into a UK format and with 3 years taken away, the expression is:

> =cdate(format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -3, now),"dd/MM/yyyy"))

This works happily when previewing the SSRS report in VS2015, however when I run it on the deployment server I get this message:

*The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter ‘StartDate’ contains an error: Conversion from string "20/10/2013" to type 'Date' is not valid. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)*

What is wrong with the expression to bring this error? and surely the same error should appear in the preview to?

Thanks

Comment: Something may be with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. I am not sure how to implement it in SSRS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be due to regionalisation differences between your dev environment and your server.  One of them will be `dd/MM/yyyy` and the other `MM/dd/yyyy`.  Where possible pass `date` types or unambiguous string formats such as `yyyy/MM/dd`.